# do-while statement with rounding causing issues

Tags: vba, if-statement, user-defined-functions, do-while

This udf should return the "g" after the sumref has been shifted, in steps of 0.05, to be within 0.1 of api. I've done it in two parts, so if api is less than sumref, it shifts the values f-j that make up sumref, up by 0.05 until sumref is within 0.1 of api. Similarly if api is greater than sumref, if shifts the values f-j down.
The second part of the function is not relevant here as it works.. That just returns a letter corresponding to the number it otherwise returns. Please help debug the loop.

```
Function AbsorbentClass(a, b, c, d, e, Optional crit As Variant = "TRUE") As Variant

f = 0.8
g = 1
h = 1
i = 1
j = 0.9

api = Application.MRound(((a + b + c + d + e) / 5), 0.05)
sumref = Application.MRound(((f + g + h + i + j) / 5), 0.05)

If api < sumref Then
    Do While Application.RoundUp(api, 1) = Application.RoundDown(sumref, 1)
        f = f + 0.05
        g = g + 0.05
        h = h + 0.05
        i = i + 0.05
        j = j + 0.05
    Loop
End If
If api > sumref Then
    Do While Application.RoundDown(api, 1) = Application.RoundUp(sumref, 1)
        f = f - 0.05
        g = g - 0.05
        h = h - 0.05
        i = i - 0.05
        j = j - 0.05
    Loop
End If

aw = g

If crit = "TRUE" Then

    ans = aw

Else

    If g < 0.15 Then
        ans = "Not classified"

    ElseIf g > 0.15 And g < 0.3 Then
        ans = "E"

    ElseIf g > 0.3 And g < 0.6 Then
        ans = "D"

    ElseIf g >= 0.6 And g < 0.8 Then
        ans = "C"

    ElseIf g >= 0.8 And g < 0.9 Then
        ans = "B"
    
    ElseIf g >= 0.9 Then
        ans = "A"
    
    End If
End If
    AbsorbentClass = ans

End Function
```

Thanks for the help so far!
I've taken your suggestions into account and also changed the logic in the do while statement to work for my purpose but it's now getting a #value error. Possibly because the ifsum statement requires a range and I've setup Udeviation as an array? How could I set it as a range that ifsum reads?

```
Function AbsorbentClass(a, b, c, d, e, Optional crit As Variant = "TRUE") As Variant

f = 0.8
g = 1
h = 1
i = 1
j = 0.9

api = Application.MRound(((a + b + c + d + e) / 5), 0.05) 'check to 
compare whether average of api or sumref is higher
sumref = Application.MRound(((f + g + h + i + j) / 5), 0.05)

Udeviation = Array(f - a, g - b, h - c, i - d, j - e) 'setting the range for the ifsum below

If api < sumref Then
    Do While Application.sumif((Udeviation), ">0") >= 0.1 'whilst sum of positive unfavorable deviations are greater than 0.1, proceed to add 0.05 to each term (f-j)
        f = f + 0.05
        g = g + 0.05
        h = h + 0.05
        i = i + 0.05
        j = j + 0.05
        Udeviation = Array(f - a, g - b, h - c, i - d, j - e) 'recalculate unfavorable deviations
    Loop
End If

'removed rest of code for now

    AbsorbentClass = g

End Function
```

Again - after trimming down the function to root out the cause of the problem I've Udeviation array into individual lines. Still not working with a #value error though - any suggestions?

```
Function AbsorbentClass(a, b, c, d, e, Optional crit As Variant = "TRUE") As Variant

f = 0.8
g = 1
h = 1
i = 1
j = 0.9

api = Application.MRound(((a + b + c + d + e) / 5), 0.05) 'check to compare whether average of api or sumref is higher
sumref = Application.MRound(((f + g + h + i + j) / 5), 0.05)

Udeviation1 = Application.If((f - a) > 0, f - a, 0)
Udeviation2 = Application.If((g - b) > 0, g - b, 0)
Udeviation3 = Application.If((h - c) > 0, h - c, 0)
Udeviation4 = Application.If((i - d) > 0, i - d, 0)
Udeviation5 = Application.If((j - e) > 0, j - e, 0)
Udevsum = Udeviation1 + Udeviation2 + Udeviation3 + Udeviation4 + Udeviation5 'setting the range for the ifsum below

If api < sumref Then
    Do While Udevsum <= 0.1 'whilst sum of positive unfavorable deviations are greater than 0.1, proceed to add 0.05 to each term (f-j)
        f = f - 0.05
        g = g - 0.05
        h = h - 0.05
        i = i - 0.05
        j = j - 0.05
        Udeviation1 = Application.If((f - a) > 0, f - a, 0)
        Udeviation2 = Application.If((g - b) > 0, g - b, 0)
        Udeviation3 = Application.If((h - c) > 0, h - c, 0)
        Udeviation4 = Application.If((i - d) > 0, i - d, 0)
        Udeviation5 = Application.If((j - e) > 0, j - e, 0)
        Udevsum = Udeviation1 + Udeviation2 + Udeviation3 + Udeviation4 + Udeviation5 'recalculate unfavorable deviations
    Loop

End If

AbsorbentClass = g

End Function
```

Comment: Maybe you could add a language tag? Is this VB, VBA, something else? Also, can you tell us in which way your current code is not doing what you want it to do (i.e. what does it do instead)?

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Apologies, of course.. It is currently returning "1", from the g=1 initial statement (at line 4).

Comment: So it is returning `1`, but for what inputs? (`a,b,c,d,e`) My guess is that your loops are not entered, thus `g` is unchanged, and you get expected result

Comment: for reference - inputs are as follows: 0.7, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 1.  I've calculated that the function should return 0.8.

Comment: With `Udeviation` (latest edit), your logic seems wrong again (if `[f:j] > [a:e]`, you increase `[f:j]`, making it even more greater than `[a:e]` thus you will never leave your loop once entered)

Comment: You're absolutely right! apologies. This loop should have -0.05 on each term from f to j. not +0.05.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at this:

```vb
api = Application.MRound(((a + b + c + d + e) / 5), 0.05)
sumref = Application.MRound(((f + g + h + i + j) / 5), 0.05)

If api < sumref Then
    Do While Application.RoundUp(api, 1) = Application.RoundDown(sumref, 1)
        f = f + 0.05
        g = g + 0.05
        h = h + 0.05
        i = i + 0.05
        j = j + 0.05
    Loop
End If
```

First, your `Do While` condition seems wrong, as you should probably use `<>` instead of `=` (you loop while `api` is different from `sumref`).

Now, assume `api < sumref` and the difference between them is such that the `Do While` is entered.
The problem here is that you never recompute `sumref`, so even if you are changing the values of `f` through `j`, the condition will not change, and you'll keep iterating your `Do While` forever.

Same applies to your second loop in case `api > sumref`.

You should probably update `sumref` like this:

```vb
api = Application.MRound(((a + b + c + d + e) / 5), 0.05)
sumref = Application.MRound(((f + g + h + i + j) / 5), 0.05)

If api < sumref Then
    ' ---------- fix comparison here ----vv
    Do While Application.RoundUp(api, 1) <> Application.RoundDown(sumref, 1)
        f = f + 0.05
        g = g + 0.05
        h = h + 0.05
        i = i + 0.05
        j = j + 0.05
        ' Recompute sumref below
        sumref = Application.MRound(((f + g + h + i + j) / 5), 0.05)
    Loop
End If
```

---

**Edit:** Here I wrote a custom `PositiveSum` function in place of `Application.sumif`:

```vb
Function AbsorbentClass(a, b, c, d, e, Optional crit As Variant = "TRUE") As Variant
    f = 0.8
    g = 1
    h = 1
    i = 1
    j = 0.9
    
    api = Application.MRound(((a + b + c + d + e) / 5), 0.05) 'check to compare whether average of api or sumref is higher
    sumref = Application.MRound(((f + g + h + i + j) / 5), 0.05)
    
    Dim UDeviation() As Variant
    UDeviation = Array(f - a, g - b, h - c, i - d, j - e) 'setting the range for the ifsum below
    
    If api < sumref Then
        Do While PositiveSum(UDeviation) >= 0.1 'whilst sum of positive unfavorable deviations are greater than 0.1, proceed to add 0.05 to each term (f-j)
            f = f - 0.05
            g = g - 0.05
            h = h - 0.05
            i = i - 0.05
            j = j - 0.05
            UDeviation = Array(f - a, g - b, h - c, i - d, j - e) 
        'recalculate unfavorable deviations
        Loop
    End If
    
    'removed rest of code for now

    AbsorbentClass = g
End Function

Function PositiveSum(arr() As Variant) As Variant
    PositiveSum = 0
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) > 0 Then
            PositiveSum = PositiveSum + arr(i)
        End If
    Next
End Function

Sub Test()
    t = AbsorbentClass(0.7, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 1)
    ' t = 0.85
End Sub
```